# show alert after clicking on submit button but without actually submitting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

At the moment, if the user is not logged in, when the user presses the button it shows the alert correctly, but then goes on to actually submit.  I would like it to show the alert but then stay on the current page (i.e. not direct to the submit page).  How can I do this?

```
<% if current_user %>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-info btn-large" %>
        </div>
    <% else %> 
        <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-info btn-large", :onclick => 'alert("You need to be logged in to add comments!")'%>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: try returning false in the onclick handler

Comment: @jul: returning `false` doesn't stop the event from propagating/bubbling... read the link in my answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a JS function to the page, and write this:

```
<%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-info btn-large", :onclick => 'submitAlert(event)'%>
```

the JS function could look like this:

```
function submitAlert(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    alert('You need to be logged in to add comments!');
    if (e.preventDefault)
    {//most browsers
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble= true;
}
```

Find out more about stopping events [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) it's quite interesting (and important to know)